# How to make sure the domain level SSL certificate is present in trust store while establishing the connection to a website?

Tags: ssl, http, java

According to my understanding, when we are trying to connect to a website/url, even if one of the certificates in the SSL certificate chain of the website is present in the trust store then connection is established successfully. But, I want to establish a connection only if the domain level certificate is present in the trust store. And I am not allowed create a new trust store instead need to use the default trust store. How can this be implemented in Java? TIA.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is certificate pinning. The way to implement it varies depending on the client, so give it a Google for your http library of choice

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately for you, that's not how PKIs were designed to work. The search for any trusted root certificate in the chain is a design feature of PKIs that ensures we don't have to install a certificate per domain on clients - bloating local trust stores with millions of certificates and complicating revocation and renewal of certificates.

What you're looking for is referred to [certificate pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) where the client validates that the certificate presented by the server has a specific thumbprint it knows and trusts before continuing any further communication with the server on the other end. It is essentially the client authenticating the server.

Depending on your particular implementation, the validation logic can be done in the application instead of at the TLS/SSL protocol layer, meaning you can do as much (CN, Key Usage Attributes, SAN) or as little (just thumbprint)validation as you want , but typically certificate thumbprints are used since they are *guaranteed to be unique. A interception proxy or other man-in-the-middle for instance can create a certificate with valid CN entry for your domain (valid domain validation), but they cannot spoof the thumbprint.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more doubt,  when we are trying to connect to a website whose domain level certificate was expired but its root certificate has validity then does connection establishment fail? During the certificate verification with the trust store,  what are the different fields that are compared? Is expiry date one among them?

Comment: Technically a separate question, but I'll provide a brief answer here in the comments. It really depends on the TLS implementation. Any RFC compliant TLS implementation (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446) would result in a "certificate_expired" error during validation of an endpoint certificate that has passed the expiry date, despite the Root CA certificate being valid - again a design feature. For other factors that form part of the validation procedure see pp. 89 - 90 in the above mentioned RFC.

Answer (score 0):

A certificate is a unique token issued to a particular individual. It is a form of identification, similar to a government-issued photo ID which most people carry.

Certificates were designed for one purpose - to convey an identity which can be verified as [authentic](https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/what-is-certificate-based-authentication/). It does this via a chain of trust.  If a client or server trusts the issuer of a certificate, then it will automatically trust the certificate.

Put in similar terms, this is similar to the TSA specifying guidelines for which forms of identification it will accept before it will let you into the security checkpoint. As long as you possess one of those valid forms of ID, the TSA will let you through. This is how the PKI is designed, and it has to be designed that way to function efficiently. So, there is no way to do this explicitly in the PKI framework.

What you're instead asking for is a separate level of identify verification beyond what PKI provides. A possible solution could be certificate pinning, but I'm not sure this gets you anywhere. If the private key is compromised, which is probably more likely than compromising a trusted CA, then you haven't gained any additional level of security.

Instead, best practice is to implement multi-factor authentication. Using the certificate itself as a second factor really doesn't make a whole lot of sense, because it isn't truly a two-factor identity. Instead, it would make more sense to use the PKI as-is, and establish a second authentication mechanism via [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_algorithm) or some other independent token generation.